# LinqPad WPF window InvalidOperationException on second execution

Tags: wpf, linqpad, freezable

I try to open a WPF window containing my WPF user control on LinaPad.

```
var w = new System.Windows.Window() { Content = myControl };
w.ShowDialog();
```

This code works only for the first time execution after opening a query tab.
If I execute the code again, then it throw InvalidOperationException saying

```
Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable
```

Is there any difference between the first time execution environment and the later execution environment in LinqPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you've created `myControl` on another thread.

The following works without error for me:

```
var w = new System.Windows.Window() { Content = "foo" };
w.ShowDialog();
```

Another solution is simply to dump myControl:

```
myControl.Dump();
```

LINQPad will then render it in its output window.